# JavaScript function within php to show more info on-click (Database Query)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

The below code is connected to a local database that holds customer information. First, the page is supposed to display the customer name and country, but should display more information for that particular customer once the name is clicked.

The problem with this code below is that it will only always display the first customers information, no matter which name is clicked. Can anyone see where I might be going wrong? Do I need to create an ID for each button (customer name)? Bare in mind that there are a lot of customers in the database and I feel that an ID for each would be very difficult to implement, especially if the database gets modified.

```
 <DOCTYPE html!>
 <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="a3.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <?php include 'nav.php';
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php include 'dbconfig.php';
    $sql ='SELECT * FROM `customers` ORDER BY `customers`.`country`    ASC';
    $q = $conn->query($sql);
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    ?>
    <div class = "main">
        <table>
            <?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>
                 <tr>
                     <td><button onclick = "showCustomer();"/><?php echo ($r['customerName'])?></td>
                     <td><?php echo ($r['country'])?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id ="extra" style="display:none">
                     <td><?php echo ($r['customerNumber'])?></td>
                     <td><?php echo ($r['contactLastName'])?></td>
                     <td ><?php echo ($r['contactFirstName'])?></td>
                     <td><?php echo ($r['phone'])?></td>
                     <td><?php echo ($r['addressLine1'])?></td>
                     <td><?php echo ($r['addressLine2'])?></td>
                     <td><?php echo ($r['city'])?></td>
                     <td><?php echo ($r['state'])?></td>
                     <td><?php echo ($r['postalCode'])?></td>
                     <td><?php echo ($r['salesRepEmployeeNumber'])?>   </td>
                     <td><?php echo ($r['creditLimit'])?></td>
                 </tr>
             <?php endwhile; ?>
        </table>
       </div>

        <div class="foot">
        <?php include 'foot.php'; ?>
       </div>
       <script>



        function showCustomer() {
            var showForm=document.getElementById('extra');
            if (showForm.style.display="none") {

               showForm.style.display ="";
                alert('ok');
                console.log(showForm);
            }
            else if (showForm.style.display=""){
                showForm.style.display ="none";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
</DOCTYPE>
```

Comment: An ID has to be unique. Geneate an unique id for each hidden element and pass the unique id to the javascript function.

Comment: Your ```<tr>``` elements are being created inside a PHP ```while``` loop.  So if you have 10 customers, you will have 10 ```<tr>``` elements with the same id "extra"

Comment: So should I create the table outside the while loop? I have over 50 customers. would this not mean creating a table for each?

Comment: @Shauna it would be better to use class="extra" instead of id="extra". Then you would only need to get the next sibling of class extra and display it. Are you open to use jQuery?

Comment: I should mention that when I get rid of the id='extra' style = 'display:none' the correct information for each customer will appear but when I set them to hide and then use the function to make them appear on click of the customers name that's when it will only return the first customers information

Comment: the javascript function document.getElementById() should only return one element, that is the reason why your function only works for the first element.

Comment: Since your extra info is on the very next <tr> of the one you click, you might use something like  var showForm = this.nextSibling and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your `<tr>` have the same `id="extra"`. As suggested, you need a different "id" for each of them, this is how : I created a variable `$i` (line 18), that is increased right after the while (line 20), inserted as parameter in the call for `showCustomer` (line 23), inserted at the end of the id "extra" (line 27), finally, on the bottom, where function `showCustomer` is declared, the parameter "index" is inserted at the end of the id "extra".

```
<DOCTYPE html!>
 <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="a3.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <?php include 'nav.php';
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php include 'dbconfig.php';
    $sql ='SELECT * FROM `customers` ORDER BY `customers`.`country`    ASC';
    $q = $conn->query($sql);
    $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    ?>
    <div class = "main">
        <table>
            <?php $i = 0;
                  while ($r = $q->fetch()):
                    $i++;           // UNIQUE INDEX FOR EACH CUSTOMER.
            ?>
                 <tr>
                     <td><button onclick = "showCustomer('<?php echo $i;?>');"/>
                          <?php echo ($r['customerName'])?></td>
                     <td><?php echo ($r['country'])?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id ="extra<?php echo $i;?>" style="display:none">
                     <td><?php echo ($r['customerNumber'])?></td>
                     <td><?php echo ($r['contactLastName'])?></td>
                     <td ><?php echo ($r['contactFirstName'])?></td>
                     <td><?php echo ($r['phone'])?></td>
                     <td><?php echo ($r['addressLine1'])?></td>
                     <td><?php echo ($r['addressLine2'])?></td>
                     <td><?php echo ($r['city'])?></td>
                     <td><?php echo ($r['state'])?></td>
                     <td><?php echo ($r['postalCode'])?></td>
                     <td><?php echo ($r['salesRepEmployeeNumber'])?>   </td>
                     <td><?php echo ($r['creditLimit'])?></td>
                 </tr>
             <?php endwhile; ?>
        </table>
       </div>

        <div class="foot">
        <?php include 'foot.php'; ?>
       </div>
       <script>



        function showCustomer( index ) { // UNIQUE INDEX AS PARAMETER.
            var showForm=document.getElementById('extra' + index); // USING INDEX.
            if (showForm.style.display="none") {

               showForm.style.display ="";
                alert('ok');
                console.log(showForm);
            }
            else if (showForm.style.display=""){
                showForm.style.display ="none";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
</DOCTYPE>
```